Having problems with the read_cv function
I tried
beaches <- read_csv(here('data','sydneybeaches')) 

and
beaches <- read_csv(here('data','sydneybeaches'))

and was expecting a return of the sydneybeaches dataset.

You should include the packages you load for your code in your question. In your case, library(readr) and library(here).

David, I think what are you looking for might be: here::set_here("<include path to data folder"). Let me know if this works for you.

The dataset you are trying to read is missing its .csv extension. Also, make sure that the dataset you are trying to read is stored in the current working directory of your project. To check your current working directory, run getwd().
Next, simply run:
beaches <- read.csv("sydneybeaches.csv", header = TRUE)

Note that the above code uses the base read.csv() function, which also works just as fine.
Alternatively, you can manually select the dataset from your working directory by running:
beaches <- read.csv(file.choose())

I hope this helps!

Cant thank you enough.

My pleasure, David!

Since loading data is a problem. I recommend using {tidyverse} alone and then an absolute path to your CSV or txt file. Try
library(tidyverse)

raw_data <- read_csv("../data/sources.csv")

print(raw_data)


The answer below is also good. Because it's using the default methods that R provided, I highly recommend that as good practice. You won't have to rely on dependencies unless it brings something meaningful.

Why is it a problem? What does readr::read_csv() add over a base approach in this particular case?

The original question (before it was edited), used read_csv() specifically. I'm not adding anything over the base functions as I've clearly suggested that as well. I'm using what David already has.
David did not put the libraries in the question, but they were using the tidyverse and here libraries. So I'm helping David adjust his work to the idea they had in mind. Otherwise, there'd be no point in asking when R already had the read.csv() function all along.
Also, I don't know where readr::read_csv() came from as that's not my solution. The problem was pulling data from a csv.
